# How to optimize an sql query to avoid maximum time execution without php.ini nor setting time limit

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables: one has url to my images and the other has url to my optimized images. I am making a selection from the tables grouped by the url of optimized images but I keep on getting a maximum fatal execution time even though I am **even limiting it to 12**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`id_pages_articles_photos`, `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo`, `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`id_ojm_peoples` AS `id_ojm_peoples_uploader` 
FROM `ojm_pages_articles_photos`, `ojm_images_optimized` 

WHERE ( (`ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo`=`ojm_images_optimized`.`url_image_original` OR `ojm_images_optimized`.`url_image_optimized`='') AND ( `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo` LIKE '%jpeg' OR `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo` LIKE '%jpg' OR `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo` LIKE '%JPEG' OR `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo` LIKE '%JPG' OR `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo` LIKE '%jpe' OR `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo` LIKE '%png' OR `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo` LIKE '%PNG' OR `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo` LIKE '%bmp' ) ) 

GROUP BY `ojm_images_optimized`.`url_image_optimized`, `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`url_articles_photo`

ORDER BY `ojm_pages_articles_photos`.`id_pages_articles_photos` DESC, `ojm_images_optimized`.`optimized_is_smaller`='Oui' 

LIMIT 0,12
```

I don't want to increase the maximum time of execution (I know how to do it in php but I don't want to do that).

How to optimize This sql query to avoid maximum time execution without php.ini nor setting time limit ? I am only selecting 12 and frankly I don't understand the maximum time of execution for just 12.

Comment: PHP's maximum execution time refers to how much time **the PHP process spends processing data**. Time spent waiting for a database to return data does not contribute to the limit. (This is apparently not true when running on Windows.)

Comment: Without a relevant data sample and seeing your schema there is not really much we can suggest, it would pretty much be guesswork. Have you verified it's actually the SQL which is the issue though? If you run the SQL independently in your SQL editor, away from PHP, is it still slow?

Comment: I'd look at the database itself, you might need some indexes. Find a tool that can explain how the query is run and where the various bottlenecks are. Because you are ordering, the limit is probably happening _after_ the more complicated logic, too, so optimizing that won't do much.

Comment: GROUP BY and SELECT DISTINCT is a very odd combination, and usually indicates something isn't right.

Comment: What is the aim of the `group by` clause as there is no aggregation ? What means the `...optimized...` in the `order by` clause ?

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of wild cards in the where clause. The server will have to check every single row of each of those columns to see which ones match, and it has to do that before it can order them, or limit them.

If all of those wild cards are necessary then will need to add indexes to those columns to speed it up.